# Ajax causing refresh on select change - not sure why

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm putting some kind of configuration area together, where basically the menu is on the left side of the screen and the actual configuration takes place on the right.

Upon clicking on a menu item, the appropriate config screen is displayed. This works with no problem.

The problem I'm having is that one config screen requires some JSON pulling from the database, using a script that I've used elsewhere that worked perfectly (though it isn't called from a page that itself was called via ajax). Basically, the JSON pull is made when a dropdown menu is changed, but I don't know why, but once the action is complete the container is refreshed. Though this only happens for some reason if I don't include the jQuery library on the called page (even though it is already present in the top parent).

If I do include the library, then for some reason when I make the change, the requested JSON pull is made 3 times (instead of 1) and no refresh happens (as it should).

Have I done something very wrong? I've tried including the jQuery/javascript processing to make onchange in the top parent, but it doesn't work at all if there - even though the ajax calls don't use 'click' but 'live'.

To call the config area on menu click:

```
$("#setting_choice ul li").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();                
    $("#setting_choice ul li").each(function(){
        $("#setting_choice ul li").removeClass("active");
    });
    $(this).addClass("active");             
    var setting = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "settings.php",
        data: "setting="+setting,
        success: function(msg){
            $("#setting_action").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){
                event.stopPropagation();
                $("#setting_action").html(msg);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The code used to make the JSON call (but not everything, as the same still happens when called) - the JSON call is successfull as I've done `console.log(j);` and seen the JSON contents:

```
$('#country').change(function(){
    alert('executed');
    $.getJSON("regions.php",{id: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
        var options = '';

        ....

        $('select#county').html(options);
        alert('complete');
    })
 });
```

I can see that the changes are made when 'complete' is alerted, but then it all refreshes for some reason...